# On an informal type of patent

Tags: patentability

What if there was an Informal Patent that has a standard  fee and no need for a patent Lawyer or a prototype. If a person pays the fee it get's registered no matter how nutty it is.

Comment: This will not result in any rights but you can apply for a patent in the U.S., however nutty. If the material you send in is in the proper format for a patent, it will be published by the USPTO in 18 months. A patent publication looks a lot like a patent but it does not imply any rights or what will happen next. You can request early publication. If you get a "Missing Parts" notice, the format wasn't right or complete or paid. Fix those but when the rejection comes in the mail just throw it away and in 6 months the application goes abandoned. But the publication of the application is forever.

Comment: Is there a way to register an idea no matter how informally , not necessarily for monetary rights but just for recognition as being the first to 'register' the idea with whatever 'recognized' registration system  this is?

Comment: Until last year US patent law had provisions for a Statutory Invention Registration. It was what you are looking for. It was little used and SIRs were done away with by the AIA law in March 2013.

Comment: Do any companies offer something like the S.I.R.s? Thank you for the info..

Comment: That would be a "defensive publication". There are several companies that offer this service - they usually charge by the page. Some I know of are IP.com, www.researchdisclosure.com, and a Linux specific one called www.defensivepublications.org

Comment: GREAT INFO. I think it's hard for any non-professional inventor or idea-promoter to get any where without spending a lot of money or having some great academic reputation. I wish there were more wealthy people and/or companies that could sponsor hopefully brilliant people like they did in the days of Leonard Euler or Pascal. (Euler was sponsored by Catherine the Great ,I think.)